# Rx - Combine new input with previous output

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, reducers

I have following case of Reducer:

```
    class XYZ Reducer(private val state: BehaviorRelay<State>) {

     override fun invoke(events: Observable<Any>): Observable<State>  =   
              events.ofType(Event::class.java).map { event ->
              handleFieldClicked(event, state.value)
    }
```

As reducer requires 2 info:

1. New event
2. Previous state

I am passing behavior relay of states  to the reducer.
I tried to find a way to have access to previous state and current event in `map{}`, like scan, all I found was `scan()` that gives current event and previous event as arguments.

Do you know any better way (an operator?) than passing `behaviorRelay` as states directly?

Answer (score 1):

You could combine `flatMap()` with `take(1)`:

```
class XYZ Reducer(private val state: BehaviorRelay<State>) {
    override fun invoke(events: Observable<Any>): Observable<State>  =   
        events.ofType(Event::class.java).flatMap { event ->
            state.take(1).map { state ->
                handleFieldClicked(event, state)
            }
        }
}
```